# Is the given manipulation of the differential operator $D$ valid?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What I know till now is, the differential operator $D$ means $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $D^2=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.

So, $D^2y=D(Dy)$,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\,\frac{d}{dx}=\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2,
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}.
$$

But today, while learning to solve second order linear differential equation; we learnt and did the following manipulation method.

Given to solve, $(D^2-3D+2)y=\sin(x)$, for Particular Integral(P.I.) we did,
$$P.I.=\frac{1}{D^2-3D+2}\sin(x)
=\frac{1}{-1-3D+2}\sin(x)=\frac{1}{1-3D}\sin(x)=\frac{(1+3D)}{1-9D^2}\sin(x)$$

That last step involves $(1-3D)(1+3D)=1-9D^2$, does that mean $D*D=D^2$, which will imply
$\frac{d}{dx}*\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. Is the last manipulation valid? Can we write $D*D=D^2$?

Comment: The $\ast$ denotes composition of the two D-operator expressions, not multiplication.

Comment: What exactly is your question, first you accept that $D^2=D·D$ is the operator for the second order derivative, then you question it again? Or is it about the abuse-of-notation where operator composition is set equal to operator multiplication? Then you should have more concerns with the operator division, as that means operator inversion.

Comment: Sahil, I have edited your main line of working so that it is clear the operator always applies to $\sin x$ since otherwise it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the differential operator (D-operator) from operator theory (note: the D-operator is linear). Multiplication of two D-operator expressions is their composition, not usual multiplication, ie, $[D\ast D]y=[D][Dy]=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)=\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=[D^2]y$ and $[f(D)\ast g(D)]y= f(D)[g(D)[y]]$

For your example,

$$\begin{align}(1-3D)(1+3D)y&=\left(I-3\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)\left(I+3\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)y\\&=\left(I-3\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)(y+3y')\\&=(y+3y')-3(y'+3y'')\\&=y-9y''\\&=\left(I-9\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\right)y\\&=(1-9D^2)y\end{align}$$

where $I$ denotes the identity map $\mathrm{id}\colon x\mapsto x$

Read the [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Properties_of_differential_operators) wiki